# Twilio Client Sending custom call parameters from nodejs server to ios client

Tags: ios, node.js, twilio, twilio-api

we're using a nodejs on the serverside, and then ios sdk (Version 3 w/support for custom parameters)

we need a way to be able to send custom parameters from our nodejs server into the client. In PHP i was able to figure it out by just sending it with the dial verb by doing

```
$dial->parameter(['name'=>'param','value'=>'value']);
```

but for nodejs i am not able to find a solution that fits with:

```
call = await client.api.calls.create({
      url: url,
      to: 'client:' + defaultIdentity,
      from: callerId,
    });
```

Comment: The PHP version there is in response to a webhook and returns TwiML, the Node.js version is using the REST API to generate a new call. Are you trying to change the method of making the call or are you looking for the same way to generate TwiML with Node.js?

Comment: @philnash im trying to look for the same way to generate the twiml with Node.Js

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can absolutely generate TwiML with the [Twilio Node.js library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/node). To generate a [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial) you need code like:

```
const VoiceResponse = require('twilio').twiml.VoiceResponse;

const response = new VoiceResponse();
const dial = response.dial({
    callerId: '+15551112222'
});
dial.number('+15558675310');

console.log(response.toString());
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Hi @philnash i was able to figure it out already. the problem was that there was no documentation on how to add parameters to a client call inside of the twilio docs (at this moment in time)

Comment: Oh, I see! I will raise that internally and try to get that documentation available.

Comment: Thanks @philnash. yes i provided the answer below for anyone that might be looking for the same solution :). I had to go inside of the twilio library to find that. I think it would be good to include custom parameters in samples on the documentaiton, I know it only came recently to the Twilio v3 sdk, but i heard you guys are about to release a stable for that right?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so, apparantly its the same way you would do it in php, except a bit different

```
function incoming() {
  const voiceResponse = new VoiceResponse();
    const dial = voiceResponse.dial({action:'http://21402340.ngrok.io/endCall'});
    let client = dial.client({
        statusCallback: 'completed',
        statusCallback: 'http://21402340.ngrok.io/endCall',
        statusCallbackMethod: 'POST'
    },'alice');
    client.parameter({name:'subscriber_name',value:'Richard abear'});

  return voiceResponse.toString();
}
```

here is a sample function that sends a custom parameter **subscriber_name** to the client's *customCallParameters*